# Fuzzyjoin / stringdist_join weight for capitalisatoin (case) mismatch (stringdist)

Tags: r, stringdist, fuzzyjoin

Working with R, I'm looking for ways to weight case (i.e., upper vs lower case) in a `string_dist_left_join()`

Here's a reproducible example:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(fuzzyjoin)

tibble1 <- tibble(words = c("Bedford", "Maidenhead", "New Forest", "Tier 3", "Citizenship", "Crown"))

tibble2 <- tibble(words = c("bedfords", "bedsford", "BEDFord", "Maidenshead", "Maidenhed", "News forest", "Tier 3", "Citisenships", "crowned", "crows"))

osa <- stringdist_left_join(tibble1, tibble2, distance_col = "distance", max_dist = 5, method = "osa", weight = c(d = 0.1, i = 0.1, s = 1, t = 1))
```

Above is the code to reproduce a fuzzyjoin powered stringsidt_left_join on a couple of tibbles. The output looks like this:

```
# A tibble: 55 x 3
   words.x words.y      distance
   <chr>   <chr>           <dbl>
 1 Bedford bedfords        0.3  
 2 Bedford bedsford        0.3  
 3 Bedford BEDFord         0.6  
 4 Bedford Maidenshead     1.4  
 5 Bedford Maidenhed       1.2  
 6 Bedford News forest     1.00 
 7 Bedford Tier 3          0.900
 8 Bedford Citisenships    1.7  
 9 Bedford crowned         1.00 
10 Bedford crows           1.00 
# … with 45 more rows
```

What I'd like is for some way to weight the capitalisation e.g., comparing Bedford to B**ED**ford: I'd like that to be a worse match than Bedford to Bedford, but better than Bedford to Bed**s**ford. The option `ignore_case = TRUE` treats BEDford as a perfect match with Bedford.

I'm liking the fuzzyjoin package, and I just discovered the custom weightings that you can pass to stringdist for each of deletion, insertion, substitution, and translocation. Which is fantastic; toys to play with, parameters to tune.

What I'd also like to be able to do is tune the case (capitalisation?) matching. I've got the option to `ignore_case = TRUE` in stringdist_left_join, (in effect, weight case as 0 or 1), but being the annoying cur that I am, I'd like to play around with weightings between 0 and 1.

Does anyone know if there's an option somewhere that I'm missing?

Or is the answer: Do it the hard way? I guess there might be a long way round involving comparing the distances before and after having run `tolower()` or computing a weighted distance comparing `ignore_case = TRUE` with `ignore_case = FALSE`, but does anyone know of a more elegant method or package that I can use to do that?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried changing the `method` i.e. `method = "soundex"`

Comment: @arkrun, yes, I've sampled all the available methods, none weights for case. Soundex matches Bedford and BEDford perfectly (0 distance) with Beford.

Answer (score 1):

You could run it twice, once with `ignore_case = TRUE` and once with `FALSE` and then find an appropriate linear combination of the two distances.

Something like `lambda * (distance_FALSE - distance_TRUE) + distance_TRUE` where `lambda` is how much less you care about capitalisation differences than other string differences.

Comment: thanks, yeah I think in lieu of a ready-made function that's going to be a good tactic.